# Distributed job management system

Tags: redis

I'm using [beeQueue](https://github.com/bee-queue/bee-queue) for video transcoding job scheduling and processing

For now everything is fine and but I'm now facing challenge of working with distributed environment like auto scaling the amazon the instances for adding more workers to process more jobs which are pending in the queue, We scale well but need to implement a system which is fail safe, I mean in case a instance on which workers were processing the job has gone shutdown and we don't get job status or events, In that case the job which were running on that instance is gone into blackhole and can't be recovered and processed again.

What I did :

1. I'm looking up for ready made solution who works fail safe in distributed env.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at beanstalkd.

Comment: @Imaskar  thanks will check it